# What is binding occurrences?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am learning [Jason Hickey's Introduction to Objective Caml](http://www.cs.caltech.edu/courses/cs134/cs134b/book.pdf).

---

I got several simple questions:

**What is `binding`?**

**What is `occurrences`?**

**What is `binding occurrences`?**

---

I ask these question because the book says:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not read this text, and am just a humble practitioner (not a theorist) but I'm pretty sure I know what the terms mean.

Binding is the association of a name with a value.

An occurrence is a single appearance of a name in an expression. If the name shows up twice, there are two occurrences.

A binding occurrence is an appearance of a name in a spot that causes it to be bound to a value. In `let x = 4 in x + 2` the first occurrence of `x` is a binding occurrence and the second is just an occurrence.

**Edit**: What the quoted text is telling you is that when a name shows up in a pattern, then a successful match of the pattern causes the name to be bound to a value.

Comment: I edited the question and gave the text about this. please have a look.

Comment: In `let x = 4 in x + 2` the first `x` *is* a pattern. You can use any pattern you want in a `let`. For example `let x, y = 3, 5 in x + y`. (See edit of my answer.)

Comment: ahh, ok, understand now. so in `let x,y=3,5 in x+y`, `x,y=3,5` are binding occurrences, because they are binding some values.

Comment: The second is _not_ "just an occurrence" but a _bound_ occurrence.